# What does [onClickEventRegion:] mean in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have a location tracking application which uses

```
startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

and

```
 startMonitoringForRegion()
```

The app was working flawlessly till september 13th . After the release of iOS 10 , the crashes have sky rocketed and I have been trying to analyse the crash logs . In the Crash Logs , I can see all the crashes are happening only on iOS 10 devices and the following error code is highlighted in stack trace in thread 0

```
libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend     
CoreLocation [CLLocationManager onClickEventRegion :]
```

Can anyone help in telling me where exactly is this

```
onClickEventRegion
```

method invoked by the Location Manager and any assistance in analysing the source of crash would also be appreciated.

Comment: Did you search for 'onClickEventRegion' in your own source code as well as any 3rd party libraries you might have included? Sounds like your app calls a selector, which does not exist.

Comment: Yes. I did . No results found :/ And it is clearly mentioned that its an issue related to CLLocationManager ? I have seen others facing issues with onClickEventLocation :

Comment: Seeing objc_msgSend related exception next to selector with a name,  which neither makes sense for CLLocationManager (it is not UI related entity) nor is known to internet community (google search for onClickEventRegion yields just one result - this post) makes the app code the primary suspect. Sorry it did not work for your troubleshooting.

Comment: I understood all that and that is the reason why I am at square zero again :/